# Visually appealing material related to partial differential equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I'm going to give a presentation on partial differential equations next week. The audience has no affiliation to mathematics, which is why I thought it would be nice to have some visually appealing material (e.g. a video of a solution of a hyperbolic PDE) possibly related to some interesting physical situations. I tried some searches on YouTube and Google, but didnt find much material I liked, so I'm hoping that maybe some of you working in that area would be willing to share some of their results.

On a related note, how would you explain what a PDE is to somebody that does not have a clear understanding of the notion of a derivative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have some luck with the (unfinished, but still quite nice) [PDE Coffee Table Book](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb.html).  At the very least it has lots of nice pictures and some good heuristics.  If you're okay with talking about PDE in fluid mechanics, you can also try [The Gallery of Fluid Motion](https://gfm.aps.org/).

For your second question I usually say something like "PDE is the language of physics."

Comment: Those are certainly very nice references!